# Numpy.loadtxt imports data as array of arrays rather than a multidimension array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a csv file, which has the first three columns like this

```
2011,12,25,...
2011,12,26....
2011,12,27,...
...
```

These columns are basically year, month and date. The other columns contain strings. There are 100 rows and 6 columns in total. I use `numpy.loadtxt` to get this into an array, using

```
input = numpy.loadtxt('file.csv', dtype='i4, i4, i4, S4, S4, S4', delimiter=',')
```

**Problem:** As I understand, this loadtxt operation should should return an array which has a shape `100x6`. However this returns an array of `100x1`, with each element being an array of `1x6`.

I want this to be normal 2D array of `100x6`. I looked up some resources on the net. It seems that since some of the columns in the csv data contains strings, I have to use the `dtype` argument, and that results in the input being a 1D array of arrays rather than a 2D array. I have tried some of the examples given in these sites, and they seem to work fine as long as all the entries in the CSV file are numbers

What I am looking for is either

- a way to import my data into a normal 2d array
- some explanation of why loadtxt imports an array of arrays

---

Sample CSV file:

```
2011,12,25,AAA,AAA,AAA
2011,12,26,BBB,BBB,BBB
2011,12,27,CCC,CCC,CCC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that `np.loadtxt` returns a 1D array, but you can still access the 'columns', which are actually *fields* in a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html):

```
array([(2011, 12, 25, b'AAA', b'AAA', b'AAA'),
       (2011, 12, 26, b'BBB', b'BBB', b'BBB'),
       (2011, 12, 27, b'CCC', b'CCC', b'CCC')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', 'S4'), ('f4', 'S4'), ('f5', 'S4')])
```

It does let you index the *fields*, but you need to do so by the names (`f0`, `f1`, `f2`...) and not indexes:

```
nt['f3']
#>>> array([b'AAA', b'BBB', b'CCC'], 
#>>>       dtype='|S4')
```

You can of course specify the `dtype` names:

```
dtype=[('MEAT', '<i4'), ('CHEESE', '<i4'), ('TOAST', '<i4'), ('BIRD', 'S4'), ('PLANE', 'S4'), ('SOCK', 'S4')]
nt = numpy.loadtxt('/home/joshua/file.csv', dtype=dtype, delimiter=',')

nt['SOCK']
#>>> array([b'AAA', b'BBB', b'CCC'], 
#>>>       dtype='|S4')
```

---

This is done to simplify a lot of complications that arise from non-homogeneous arrays.

Comment: An easier way to specify the names is to use `genfromtxt` instead: `np.genfromtxt('file.csv', dtype='i4,i4,i4,S4,S4,S4', names='Y,M,D,A,B,C')`  If the file.csv has header names, you can just say `names=True` and it'll load them from the file.

Comment: +1 Thanks @Veedrac and @askewchan. I tried using both `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt`. Both work fine. Currently I am using `genfromtxt` because as @askewchan pointed out, it is indeed easier. Thanks for the help!